# What does `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole` expect in the claim?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, claims

I have a claim called `groups`.  When I setup my `TokenValidationParameters` I set `RoleClaimType` to be `groups`.

When the claims come through, the `groups` claim has a value like this:

> "something,some other thing,more things,other other things"

But when I call:

```
User.IsInRole("some other thing");
```

The result is `False`.

**What does `IsInRole` expect in that claim?**

Meaning does it want semicolon separation, comma separation (that does not seem to be working), space delimited, or a single value (not sure how it could be an "in" check if it is a single value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsInRole` wants the claim to contain the value you are looking for.
This is why it won't work in your case.
What you can do is make a claims transformation like this:

```
public class AzureAdGroupsSplitClaimTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var identities = principal.Identities;
        if (identities == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(principal);
        }

        var result = new List<ClaimsIdentity>();
        var groupsClaimSplit = false;

        // Iterate each identity the user may have, make sure to keep all of them
        foreach (var identity in identities)
        {
            var groupClaims = identity.FindAll("groups").ToList();
            if (groupClaims.Count != 1 || !groupClaims[0].Value.Contains(','))
            {
                // groupClaims.Count == 0: Identity does not have groups
                // groupClaims.Count > 1: Identity has more than one groups claim, already split
                // The only groups claim does not contain a comma: Identity has one group, no need to split
                result.Add(identity);
                continue;
            }

            var claim = groupClaims[0];
            var groups = claim.Value.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var claims = groups.Select(s => new Claim("groups", s));
            var updatedIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity, claims);
            result.Add(updatedIdentity);

            groupsClaimSplit = true;
        }

        // Nothing was done to the original identities, may as well just return the original principal
        if (!groupsClaimSplit)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(principal);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsPrincipal(result));
    }
}
```

And then register it in the service collection:

```
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, AzureAdGroupsSplitClaimTransformation>();
```

Now you should get additional group claims for the user with only a single value.
Your role check should then work.
Though it is a bit odd to use IsInRole for this purpose,
you could also use `User.HasClaim("groups", "your-group-id")`.